# NSMutableArray property getting autoreleased?

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSMutableArray property defined in my Brain model.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *stockColors;
```

The mutable array gets filled with objects during the Brain init.

In my view controller viewDidLoad function I do

```
*Brain brain = [[Brain alloc]init];
NSLog(@"Brain stockColors is %@", brain.stockColors);
```

This works well, and it logs a memory address as expected.

Then in the same view controller I have an "addButtonPressed" action declared linked to a UIButton in the .xib.

In my addbuttonPressed action if I try and do the exact same log

```
NSLog(@"Brain stockColors is %@", brain.stockColors);
```

The program crashes!

If I do

```
NSLog(@"Brain stockColors is %@", brain);
```

I get an address for the brain... so the brain exists..  but for some reason it seems that brain.stockColors is getting released or something by the time I get to the addButtonPressed action.

Can anyone explain what would cause it to get autoreleased?

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand this. What is `Brain` class ? and why is not `Brain *brain` ? And what is the class name in which `stockColors` and `IBAction` are used ?

Comment: Can you show us `Brain`'s init method?

Comment: Besides the fact that `*Brain brain` is invalid syntax, the variable `brain` shouldn't even exist outside of `viewDidLoad` since it's a local variable, so writing `brain.stockColors` there shouldn't compile. It is much more helpful if you post real code rather than some code you wrote in your web browser that has 20 irrelevant problems and might not even include the actual mistake that's causing you grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you left out the important code... the actual `Brain` init call I am going to say that when you create your mutable array you are assigning to the instance variable and not the property.

```
//The Brain init method should contain something similar to this
self.stockColor = [NSMutableArray array];

//stockColor = [NSMutableArray array]; would be incorrect and get autoreleased
```

Comment: This is correct!  Once I added "self" in the init, it worked!